# Message: Undefined variable: info in view

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am fetching data from database in CodeIgniter. Data is showing up but this error is also coming.

Model:

```
public function database()
{
    $this->load->database();

    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM info");

    $result = $sql->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function home()
{
    $this->load->model('Mymodel');
    $this->Mymodel->result();



    $data['info'] = $this->Mymodel->database();

    $this->load->view('home',$data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php
$u = 0;

foreach ((array) $info as $inform) {
    $u++; 
    echo '<tr>
              <td>'.$u.'</td>

              <td>'.$inform['u_name'].'</td>
              <td>'.$inform['u_email'].'</td>
              <td>'.$inform['u_phone'].'</td>
              <td>'.$inform['u_comment'].'</td>
              <td>'.$inform['u_date'].'</td>

          </tr>';
}
?>
```

error:
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: info

Filename: views/home.php

Comment: Does the controller class extends CI_Controller?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yes

Comment: I don't understand why you put `$this->Mymodel->result();` . Try a var_dump() after function called.